# Is there a way we can dynamically add pseudo-element css as inline css

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, webforms

Is there a way i can add below css as inline css using C# from codebehind

**CSS**

```
.slide .btn_six::after {
    content: " ECHNOLOGY";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slide">
<a target="_blank" href="#" class="post-badge btn_six">T</a>
</div>
```

I have to list multiple articles and each article belongs to a category and each category i have to show in an animated manner where only first caharacter of word will be visible and when user hovers over it it then reveal whole category name as shown in template [link](http://news365.bdtask.com/Demo/DemoNews365/home-style-two.html#).

I want to do this using C# from the codebehind file itself as it will be easy

I looked for example but could not find any relevant example

Comment: What about just using CSS, e.g.  including the whole word but setting `.post-badge { visibility: hidden; }` and `.post-badge:first-letter { visibility: visible; }`?

Comment: @denmch, could you explain more it looks if i understood should work

Comment: The contents of the `a` element might hold the entire word, e.g., Technology. Setting it to `visibility: hidden` but with `:first-letter` set to visible, you’ll see T but not echnology, though it will reserve space. You can add a third rule that sets the whole element to visible on hover.

Comment: @denmch, i tried but it is not showing the first character https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rpPKvJ

Comment: Even though it is possible I recommend not doing it this way, since you can very well do it just with css. Looks like you need css with dynamic content, in that case you can generate the html with data atrribute and in css show content based on it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes . It depends a bit on what browsers you have to support.

Comment: @Learning try setting `a` to `display: block;` or `inline-block`.

Comment: @denmch, i tried, it doesn't work

Comment: Works for me, but I’m heading to bed. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done.

A hover event is only possible to do from the client side with JavaScript or by using CSS [`:hover` selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp). While it could be possible to wire it up to send a request back to the server to write a segment of HTML and then replace the HTML element in JavaScript, this would not be very practical. It is much simpler just to write the class on the client side without making a round trip to the server or better yet, just set a CSS `:hover` and be done with it.